# Configure maven to download dependency in parallel threads

Tags: multithreading, maven, download, dependencies, multipart

Our build are taking time as we download large artifacts which is the bottle neck in the overall build process. Increasing number of threads is not helping. I couldn't find any dependency plugin configuration to download the file using multiple threads or multi-part download. Is it possible in maven to download dependency artifact in multiple parts in parallel?

Please note that I need an individual file to be downloaded in parts in parallel. Not multiple files with each being downloaded in one thread.

Verified here https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/, can't find any support for multipart download.

Comment: What kind of file is that? How is it downloaded? I guess it's not a regular Maven dependency, right? I can't imagine a regular dependency would be that big that you need to download it this way.

Comment: Are we talking of a single file? Furthermore of what file size are we talking about?

Comment: These are jar files downloaded from artifactory. File size is in range of 200MB and there are several such files. Artifactory and build machines are in different continents.